# Calculation of Set A - Set B in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 files: File A contains 11746774 tweets and File B contains 704060 tweets. I want to calculate the tweets that are not present in File A - File B i.e. 1174674 - 704060 = 470614. PFB program. MatchWise-Tweets.zip contains the list of 49 files where tweets are stored in 49 separate files. Intention is to fetch the file-names and pass each of the file-names to get the list of tweets present in each of the 49 files.

```
import csv
import zipfile

totTweets = 1174674
matchTweets = 704060
remaining = totTweets - matchTweets     
lst = []
store = []
total = 0       
#opFile = csv.writer(open('leftover.csv', "wb"))
mainFile = csv.reader(open('final_tweet_set.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|') 
with zipfile.ZipFile('MatchWise-Tweets.zip', 'r') as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        lst.append(name)

for getName in lst:
    inFile = csv.reader(open(getName, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in inFile:
        store.append(row)

length = len(store)
print length

count=0
for main_row in mainFile:
    flag=0
    main_tweetID = main_row[0]
    for getTweet in store:
        get_tweetID = getTweet[0]
        if main_tweetID == get_tweetID:
            flag = 1
            #print "Flag == 1 condition--",flag
            break
    if flag ==1:
        continue
    elif flag == 0:
        count+=1
        remaining-=1
        #print "Flag == 0 condition--"
        #print flag
        opFile.writerow(main_row)
        print remaining
```

Actual Result - `573655`

Expected Result - `470614`

File Structure -

```
566813957629808000,saddest thing about this world cup is that we won't see mo irfan bowling at the waca in perth :( #pakvind #indvspak #cwc15 @waca_cricket,15/02/2015 15:19
566813959076855000,"#pakvsind 50,000 tickets for the game were sold out in 20 minutes #cwc15 #phordey #indvspak",15/02/2015 15:19
566813961505366000,think india will give sohail his first 5 for.. smh.. #indvspak #cwc15,15/02/2015 15:19
```

First column is tweet-id, second column is tweet-text and third column is tweet-date. I just want to know if there is an issue in this program because I am not getting desired results.

Comment: you could possibly make sets from tweetids and then use the built-in set differencing functions in python. see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: @Dinesh - Thanks for your suggestion. But before I try something totally new, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: is it possible that some tweets are present in both sources?

Comment: Yes. There are tweets present into both. However, the bigger set has some which is not present in smaller. I want to find that one. I guess I found the problem. I am not converting the tweetIDs into int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
import difflib
file1 = "PATH OF FILE 1"
file1 = open(file1, "r")
file2 = "PATH OF FILE 2"
file2 = open(file2, "r")
diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
file1.close()
file2.close()
delta = ''.join(x[2:] for x in diff if x.startswith('- '))
print delta
```

Comment: Posted in answer, what you meant. Please let me know if this is fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
import difflib
import csv
file1 = open('final_tweet_set.csv', 'rb') 
file2 = open("matchTweets_combined.csv","rb")
diff = difflib.ndiff(file1.readlines(), file2.readlines())
file1.close()
file2.close()
delta = ''.join(x[2:] for x in diff if x.startswith('- '))

#print delta
fout = csv.writer(open("leftover_new.csv","wb"))
for eachrow in delta:
    fout.writerow(eachrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes the assumption that your files do not contain duplicates. This may not be the case and why your result isn't right.

Using sets over lists should make it easier to get the right result and also increase the speed (as it would only be comparing the tweet id rather than the entire tweet and its metadata).

The following uses sets, and is a bit more compact and readable. It's not quite complete, you'll have to add the bit that opens the zip file and the opfile (and closes them).

```
tweet_superset = set() # your store
for getName in lst:
    inFile = csv.reader(open(getName, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    tweet_supetset.update(entry[0] for entry in inFile)
    # using a set means we ignore any duplicate tweets in the 49 source files.

length = len(tweet_superset)
print length

seen_tweets = set()
for entry in mainFile:
    id_ = entry[0]
    if id_ in tweet_superset:
        if id_ in seen_tweets:
            print "Error, this tweet appears more than once in mainFile:", entry
        else:
            opFile.writerow(entry)
            seen_tweets.add(id_)

count = len(seen_tweets)
print count
```

Comment: There are no duplicates in the file. I have harvested this data and made sure there arent any duplicates.

Comment: Getting this error: tweet_superset.update(id_ for id_, text, datetime in inFile)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Sorry, I assumed each entry in your row was `id,tweet_text,datetime`, with no other fields. I've made a change to the code to remove the unpacking.